# Computed method/property decorators are not yet supported

Tags: typescript, antlr, antlr4, ts-jest, babel-jest

I got errors

```
    SyntaxError: /Users/myproject/src/libts/antlr4ts/misc/Array2DHashSet.ts: Computed method/property decorators are not yet supported.
      23 | const LOAD_FACTOR: number = 0.75;
      24 |
    > 25 | export class Array2DHashSet<T extends { toString(): string; }> implements JavaSet<T> {
         |        ^
      26 |      @NotNull
      27 |      protected comparator: EqualityComparator<T>;
```

and my .babelrc.json is

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "current"
                }
            }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
            {
                "legacy": true
            }
        ],
        [
            "@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators",
            {
                "legacy": true
            }
        ],
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
            {
                "loose": true
            }
        ],
        "babel-plugin-parameter-decorator",
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring",
            {
                "useBuiltIns": true
            }
        ],
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ],
    "env": {
        "test": {
            "plugins": [
                [
                    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
                    {
                        "legacy": true
                    }
                ],
                [
                    "@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators",
                    {
                        "legacy": true
                    }
                ],
                [
                    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                    {
                        "loose": true
                    }
                ],
                "babel-plugin-parameter-decorator",
                [
                    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring",
                    {
                        "useBuiltIns": true
                    }
                ],
                "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
            ],
            "presets": [
                [
                    "@babel/preset-env",
                    {
                        "targets": {
                            "node": "current"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "@babel/preset-typescript"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am copying codes from https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4ts into my repo to try it. but when I run `jz test`, I got the above errors. it seems that I need use babel plugins to compile the antlr4ts source codes. but I got many errors. Currently, I got the above error.
Any babel config or setting missing? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error position is wrong. It's likely the `@NotNull` decorator that is a problem. To make this compile you have to enable experimental decorators in your tsconfig.json file:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
    }
}
```